# Android notification flags require pipe?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set an android notification flag like `Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR`. When searching online I see `myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;` I realize that it needs the `|=` or else it doesn't work... but my curiosity has gotten the best of me because I've never seen it before.

Comment: Bitwise OR Notification.flags with Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR and assign the result to Notification.flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a pipe, it's a bitwise operator.

It's used instead of multiple flags for a single operation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html
http://sys.cs.rice.edu/course/comp314/10/p2/javabits.html

Comment: Is there a reason not to use an & or ^ in this case?

Comment: This is something I don't know :P I've only used them myself when configuring the ActionBar - I expect a better, more complete answer will come along in a moment; I just wanted to give you some better keywords to search for :)

Comment: Yes.  In general, these flag changes are additive.  Bitwise OR'ing them in maintains the previous flags, while also setting the one specified.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I will keep the question opened for now!

Comment: fwiw, `x |= y` is to `x = x | y` as `x += y` is to `x = x + y`